# sensors-detect not detecting or adding modules (22.04)

Tags: 22.04, fancontrol, sensors, lm-sensors

So I have the following system:

```
AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8 Cores
32 GB DDR4
GIGABYTE X570S AORUS ELITE AX
GIGABYTE NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti Rev 2.0 8GB
NZXT Kraken x53 AIO Cooler (2 fans 1 pump)
Corsair Commander Pro XT with 5 PWM+RGB Fans and 1 temperature sensor
```

Running Ubuntu:

```
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
```

with Kernel:

```
Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to be able to control my fans with fancontrol/pwmconfig but it's not working.
I think it has to do with the fact that during the sensor-detect,
no modules are loaded and the module configuration is skipped for some reason.

After it, running pwmconfig does not work because it reports:

```
 /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

can someone help me how to get sensor-detect to load the correct modules so I can hopefully at least control/monitor some of the fans in my PC?

here is the full output of my sensors-detect:

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. X570S AORUS ELITE AX [-CF]
# Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64
# Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor (25/33/2)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           Success!
    (driver `k10temp')
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8689
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): y
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Using driver `i2c-piix4' for device 0000:00:14.0: AMD KERNCZ SMBus

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at b:00.0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at b:00.0 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y
y
Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at b:00.0 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at b:00.0 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y
Client found at address 0x4a
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410/ADT7420'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7411'...                     No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP435'...                   No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Client found at address 0x4b
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410/ADT7420'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7411'...                     No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP435'...                   No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7481'...                     No

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at b:00.0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 17h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

No modules to load, skipping modules configuration.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always important to read the details in the output from `sensors-detect`.

In this case you have `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8689` in your output.

Searching the net for that, there is a solution that works for 0x8688 that may work for you. https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/154

Make sure you have `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` in your grub config.
Then force load the driver with `modprobe it87 force_id=0x8628` to see if the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

At a terminal try this
`sudo apt install lm-sensors`
wait for it
`sudo sensors-detect`
fill out the questionaire
`sensors`
check output
`sudo apt install psensor`
wait for it
You cna then run psensor from the Applications menu.